# Using Vimeo API and customize?

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

I'm using Vimeo's API mostly because I want to play the video through my own button.

The only problem I came across is that when I'm trying to change the buttons content like `<button>Play</button>` to `<button>Play me</button>` the video won't play. Why is that?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h28szz6L/1/) to see what I mean.

The JS from Vimeo's API.

```
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var status = $('.status');

    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');

        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

    // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });

    function onPause(id) {
        status.text('paused');
    }

    function onFinish(id) {
        status.text('finished');
    }

    function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
        status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question...

What I figured out was that the API is looking for what's inside the button. In this case:

Play...

So what I did was `<button data-action="play">Play this video</button>`

and in the JS I did following thing:

```
$('button').bind("click", function() {

player.api($(this).data("action"));

});
```